# Problem is selenium, python, beginner in coding

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I received this error when trying to run my code, let me know what I can do. If needed I'll post the full code here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\FB\GUI.py", line 104, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\FB\GUI.py", line 65, in main
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
 File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 268, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 359, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19042 x86_64)
```

Comment: Please post a small reproducible code that causes your issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We can only tell you what is wrong with code that you show to us. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so that we don't have to sort through the full code. Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236 - "let me know what I can do" is not an actionable question. "Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?" works, but only after you've [tried to figure it out yourself first - which includes reading documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/).

Answer (score 0):

you need to install a chrome driver and tell selenium where to find it.
by either:

- updating your PATH
- using executable_path when instantiating a new driver

then
install chrome
and tell chrome driver where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The message indicate that the chrome driver was either not installed or not found by Python code.

Check the following link to setup chrome drivers:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

The best way is to download the binary from following link:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Once done, you can identify the path to the driver present in the local directory like following:

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Chrome\\chrome64_55.0.2883.75\\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
print("Chrome Browser Invoked")
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the driver installed for your browser, or the python code cannot find it. On the official Selenium website you can find detailed instructions for installing the appropriate driver: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/ .